# How to echo PHP variable above the code

Tags: php

I want to echo an variable $download at the top of my page . But the variable works only after the code , ie. echoing after the below code .The below link generates an unique id image from database. i would like to display that image url at the top.Thanks for help,

works

```
<?php $download = " http://www.domain.com/$rowimg[idimage]"; ?>
<?echo $download ?>
```

not works

```
<?echo $download ?>
<?php $download = " http://www.domain.com/$rowimg[idimage]"; ?>
```

Comment: You can't echo something if it doesn't exist yet.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you surprised that you cannot echo a variable before you assign anything to it?

Comment: by that logic we could know if theres live after death!

Comment: @ede: you need to echo & assign in the same line. Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550350/how-to-echo-php-variable-above-the-code/11550430#11550430) below.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `$rowimg[idimage]` seems to indicate that you are trying to display a value from a DB result.  If that is the case then what are you doing?

Answer (score 3):

You can't... and nor should you want to.

Do all of your logic for your page before you output any HTML.  Then, output all of the relevant HTML based on data in your variables.

Comment: by using functions is it possible?

Comment: @ede - A function cannot resolve the core issue.  At some point the value must be initialized before it can be referenced.  I've added an example that uses a function to reference the value, but it still requires that the value be known before attempting to display it.

Comment: @ede why not echo and assign at the same time in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your $download variable before you can call it

When you call:

The variable $download has no value assigned to it during the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, echoing & assigning in the same *first* line:

```
<?php echo $download="http://www.domain.com/$rowimg[idimage]"; ?>
```